# MVC 5: Controller's action based routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to have different routing based upon controller's action?

For example:

**Default routing**

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

this would make the url look like

```
localhost:/Home/{someaction}/{id}
```

if the controllers action is

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
   return Content("Sup?");
}
```

but lets suppose I have this action

```
public ActionResult AnotherAction(Guid productCategoryId, Guid productId)
{
   return content("Hello!");
}
```

if I don't have any custom routing then the route would look like

```
localhost:/Home/AnotherAction?productCategoryId=someGuidId&productId=someGuidId
```

but for this action if I want the route to look like

```
localhost/Home/AnotherAction/productCategoryGuidId/productGuidId
```

how would I do that?

I have added a custom route

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "appointment",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{appointmentId}/{attendeeId}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Home",action = "Index", appointmentId = "",attendeeId="" }
    );
```

but how do I say a controller's action to use that route and not default route.

Also, I read there is [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) in MVC 5. Would this help in my case? How would I use it in my case?

Comment: Custom routes is the way to go. Be sure to add them first and specify the default route at the end.

Comment: So I don't have to tell my controller to use routemap with certain name if I have custom route?

Comment: You could. I can't really provide a counter argument. Maybe, scalability wise, it would be better _not_ to use the attribute. What happens if you have another (or many other) action(s) that needs to use this route? You need to decorate each action. If you set up the routes correctly, the server will automatically do that for you. As a rule of thumb, you need to set the most specific routes first and the most general last. As @lnanikian mentioned, the routes are check in the order they're defined. After a valid rule is find, no other rules will be checked. The general route will always match.

Answer (score 0):

Register your custom MapRoute before your default Route. The order of which come first counts in the table route.
Routes are applied in the order in which they appear in the RouteCollection
object. The MapRoute method adds a route to the end of the collection, which means that routes are generally applied in the order in which we add them.

Hope It will help